# Retrieve data from API while launch image is shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to retrieve data from web service while launch image is being shown?
Or I will not show a launch image but I'll just use a view controller with an image (launch image), and retrieve data when that view controller is currently viewed?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have any control over the launch image, so the second option you listed is how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW25) suggests to "Start Instantly", not to use a launch image, but instead to show the actual interface as soon as possible, and if it's not ready yet, to show an activity indicator, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The launch image is there simply because you application's delegate and main view controller are NOT yet loaded into memory. Par Apple documentation: launch images are there to look like the first view controller to give the perception that your application starts faster than it is truly is.

What this all means is that while the launch image is shown, you aren't getting anything but setup code done. The closet you could get loading something from the web on start up would be a "viewWillLoad" or "xxxWillLoad" type method. Loading an extra view controller is a waste of the user's time and (although considerably small) memory.